# How to disable Window Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel (Tabtip.exe) settings

Tags: c#, .net, windows-11

I would like to disable the upper right corner setting or the layout setting inside the on-screen keyboard (Tabtip.exe) by modifying the registry or c# code.

I have tried modifying the registry entries below, but none of them are working.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7

EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke =0

EnableFloatingHandwriting=0

[image]
[image]